# how to merge two file with awk?

Tags: awk

I have two files which are in same order and they have the same number of rows:

file1(only 2 columns):

```
562_201 RIR1
562_202 RIR1
562_203 RIR1
562_204 RIR1
562_205 RIR1
562_206 RIR1
562_207 RIR1
562_208 RIR1
562_209 RIR1
562_210 WR1 
562_211 WR1 
562_212 WR1
```

file2 (I should say that file2 has more than  million rows!):

```
562_201 0101
562_202 0101
562_203 0101
562_204 0101
562_205 0101
562_206 0101
562_207 0101
562_208 0101
562_209 0101
562_210 0101
562_211 0101
562_212 0101
```

and I want to merge them to get:

```
562_201 RIR1 0101
562_202 RIR1 0101
562_203 RIR1 0101
562_204 RIR1 0101
562_205 RIR1 0101
562_206 RIR1 0101
562_207 RIR1 0101
562_208 RIR1 0101
562_209 RIR1 0101
562_210 WR1  0101
562_211 WR1  0101
562_212 WR1  0101
```

thanks!

Comment: `I have more than million columns` may I know how on earth that file is getting created?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `join` command:

```
$ join file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: `join` requires the files to be sorted on the join fields. if both files are sorted by column 1, you're in luck.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure, but the `join` command may load both files into memory.  That may be problematic if one or both of the files is enormous.

This should avoid the problem by only loading the smaller file into an array in memory, then joining data through a pipe.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Load file1 into an array...
BEGIN {
  while (getline < "file1") {
    file1[$1]=$0;
  }
}

{
  key=$1;    # Store the key
  $1="";     # Blank the key (now $0 starts with the field separator)
  print file1[key] $0;
}
```

Usage:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ ./join.awk file2
562_201 RIR1 0101
562_202 RIR1 0101
562_203 RIR1 0101
562_204 RIR1 0101
562_205 RIR1 0101
562_206 RIR1 0101
562_207 RIR1 0101
562_208 RIR1 0101
562_209 RIR1 0101
562_210 WR1 0101
562_211 WR1 0101
562_212 WR1 0101
```

As Glenn suggested, the notation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {file1[$1]=$0; next} {$1=file1[$1]; print}' file1 file2
```

is a more classical approach to the same idea of loading a first file into an array.

If these files, with millions of rows, are too large to be stored in memory, you can also step through each file in its own pipe, loading only one line at a time from each file into memory:

```
$ awk '{getline line < "file1"; print line,$2}' file2
```

This reads the lines in file2, and for every line also reads a line from file1 into a variable, and then prints the variable and the extra field from file2. Only one line at a time is stored in memory.

As-is, it assumes that the first field always matches up in each file -- that is, there's no error checking. If you want some, it's easy enough to implement:

```
$ awk '{getline line < "file1"; split(line,a); if(a[1]!=$1) {exit(1)} print line,$2}' file2
```

This will exit with an exit status of 1 if `$1` doesn't match.

Comment: You can write that like this: `awk 'NR==FNR {file1[$1]=$0; next} {$1=file[$1]; print}' file1 file2`. Also you have to hold the entire file1 in memory, so make sure it's not too huge.

Comment: Absolutely, and I think I did it the other way to help demonstrate the last two examples, which do not use the array. If one is concerned about memory use, one can just read on-demand from multiple file handles.

Answer (score 5):

awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next;}gsub($1,$1" "a[$1])' file1 file2
```

Comment: using NR, FNR to save first file's data, and `gsub` to output  with common key ?

Answer (score 2):

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{$3=""; print}'
```

Explanation:

1. `paste f1 f2` : merge line by lines
2. `$3=""; print` : to remove the repeated column

Comment: Always is better if you add a brief explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @ianaya89: true! lets do it!