# How can I combine files based on a common field?

Tags: file, bash, unix, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [merge two files by key if exists in the first file / bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364455/merge-two-files-by-key-if-exists-in-the-first-file-bash-script)

I am trying to think of good way to combine these two selections of text (these are example of text that is in a similar format that I would be working on), based on the number prefacing the colon. This would be done in a bash environment, I've tried thinking of ways in which I could do it using cut along with other commands, but I have not been able to come up with anything that would work.

```
selection 1
1:829ede2828e9
2:893h8ew9nediucn
3:mdheuwe883ud8932

selection 2
1:stack
2:over
3:flow
```

the output would be something along the lines of

```
1:stack:829ede2828e9
2:over:893h8ew9nediucn
3:flow:mdheuwe883ud8932
```

so it would essentially be combining and matching the files based on the number prefacing the colon. This code would be used to process around 39,000 lines of text. I am stumped at this point in time so I would really appreciate any help I can get, thanks! also forgot to mention the numbers wont be consistent (1,3,4,5,9,11,22 for example), although both files/sets of text will have the same set of numbers.

Comment: What about this: [join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9635791/957560) ?

Comment: ^ Do that if they're sorted.  If they're not, it's two steps to sort them first.  `sort`.

Comment: I assume the numbers *aren't* sorted or contiguous?  Are they unique?  In any case, 39,000 lines isn't too many, so you can do the whole thing in memory.  I suggest using awk to split the line into a number => text associative array, and combine the output.  You could equally well use any scripting language with support for associative arrays (Python, Ruby, Php, Perl etc) for this.

Comment: the numbers would be sorted, but they will not be consistent though, so there could be
1:sdds
3:sddsdsdsd
4:ddsds
7:cdds

and so on, although both sets of data would have the same numbers

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Probably be a good idea to add that case (where there might be missing numbers) to your question, so that people can take account of that when coming up with solutions

Comment: would you guys know how I could use join in this particular particular instance by any chance?

Comment: Huh, `join` is smarter than I thought, I think it'll do what you want -see Olaf's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [join](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) like this:

```
join -t: selection2.txt selection1.txt
```

Comment: *Providing the files are sorted.

Comment: @therefromhere Of course, but they are as lacrosse1991 confirmed in the comments.

Comment: Aye, but worth mentioning that in your answer for the benefit of future visitors.