# How to get a pattern from a file and search in another file in unix

Tags: unix, search, awk

I have 2 files File1 and File2.
File1 has some values separated by "|". For example,

```
A|a
C|c
F|f
```

File2 also has some values separated by "|". For example,

```
a|1
b|2
c|3
d|4
e|5
```

Means 2nd column in File1 is resembled with 1st column of File2.

I have to create 3rd file File3 with expected output

```
A|a|1
C|c|3
```

I tried to take each record in loop and searched for  that in File2 using "awk".

It worked, but the problem is both File1 and File2 are having more than 5 million records.

I need an optimized solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge two file with awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635712/how-to-merge-two-file-with-awk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a { print a[$1],$1,$2 }' OFS="|" file1 file2 > file3
```

More clearer way:

```
awk  'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="|";} NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a { print a[$1],$1,$2 }' file1 file2 > file3
```

**As per @Kent suggestion:**

If your `file2` have more than two columns that you want it in `file3` then,

```
awk  'BEGIN{ OFS=FS="|";} NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a { print a[$1],$0 }' file1 file2 > file3
```

Here,

`FS`  - Field Separator

`OFS` - Output Field Separator

Comment: just found my answer has no big difference from yours. you can simplify it a bit: `print a[$1],$0`. I just remove mine and vote yours up.

Comment: Please tell from where I can read more about awk. Since some similar operations I want to do on multiple files. Like in example, I had given only 2 files, but I want to do the same on multiple files. So, I want to learn this. Please suggest a good source to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `join` was created to do:

```
$ join -t '|' -o '1.1,1.2,2.2' -1 2 -2 1 file1 file2
A|a|1
C|c|3
```

`man join` for more details and pay particular attention to the files needing to be sorted on the join fields (i.e. 2nd field for file1 and 1st field for file2), as your posted sample input is.